# Wordpress JSON feed to viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress

I'm trying to show a Wordpress post inside my app. First i've used the JSON feed from wordpress to add the content to a NSDictionary. The problem is that the images inside the content is html. What is the best solution in order show the content in a view, so it looks integrated.

This is a log message of the content. What would be the best way to show this inside my viewController?

```
"Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
\n
\n&nbsp;
\n
\n<a href=\"http://URL/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Digital-Board-2.png\">    <img class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-5\" src=\"http://URL/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Digital-Board-2.png\" alt=\"Digital Board 2\" width=\"1024\" height=\"704\" /></a>\n\n\nJeg elsker kage"
```

Comment: Are you attempting to scrape the HTML or do you have a JSON feed?

Comment: well from wordpress this is the output i get! how can i show this as text and images and not as code in my app